# Android and HTML5 Number Input AutoSubmit Behavior

Tags: javascript, android, html, form-submit

I am writing an web page that has a form with a single zipcode field for estimating shipping and taxes.  I would like the form to submit once the user hits the enter key on the numeric keypad.

e.g.

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" id="ProductCode" value="12345" />
    Enter zip: <input type="number" id="ZipCode" />
</form>
```

The current behavior is apparently not obvious enough:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ZipCode').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val().length == 5) {
            $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
    });
    $('#ZipCode').focus(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
</script>
```

Ideally I would like the form to autosubmit when the enter key is closed or (if possible) when the soft keyboard is closed by the user.  Is there any way to do this using JavaScript in the Android browser?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add hidden button. This works at least in Chrome. When form has a submit button it is automatically triggered when enter is pressed.

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" id="ProductCode" value="12345" />
    Enter zip: <input type="number" id="ZipCode" />
    <button type="submit" style="display:none">
</form>
```

The you can use `$("form").submit(function(){ // run when form is submitted })` to implement the submit code.

Comment: The problem I am having is that submit() is not firing on my test device when enter on the number pad is being entered.  The enter key does not even register when I try and capture the scan code in onKeyPress, onKeyUp, onKeyDown event handlers.  All the enter key seems to do on my device (Galaxy S II) is close the number keypad.  I've tried both the implementations above but without any change in behavior.  I almost wonder if it's the UI overlay...

Comment: @KrisOye I see what you mean now. I know the android "enter" key is a bi quirky and doesn't register to event handlers but I thought it would at least submit the form (hardware and software keyboard) with a button. Don't have any other solution in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Put a submit button in the form and the enter key will submit the form naturally.

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" id="ProductCode" value="12345" />
    Enter zip: <input type="number" id="ZipCode" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" style="visibility: hidden" /> 
</form>
```

If you need to validate bind to the form submit event, and perform your necessary validation there.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var invalid = $('#ZipCode').val().length !== 5;
    if(invalid)
        return false
});
```